# Actionscript-Make a glow around ONLY the image in a loaded transparent PNG?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

Can anyone tell me if its possible to make a glow filter effect around ONLY the image in a loaded transparent PNG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Simply apply a filter to the Loader and it will respect the images alpha channel.

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("image.png"));
loader.filters = [ new GlowFilter(0xff0000) ];
addChild(loader);
```